# K2: Search Extra fields

Tags: k2, search, images

My site is a photography gallery website built with K2. Each K2 item is a photo. I have attached extra fields to each of the photos, for example, resolution, shot by what camera, style, etc. I'd like to allow users to search and sort the photos by these extra fields. It seems to me that normal search will only search K2 item's introtext and fulltext, is there anyway to search these extra fields?

Furthermore, is there any extension better than K2 to handle these kinds of contents?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this commercial extension for K2 that does search results by extrafields and much more. See [here](http://getk2.org/extend/extensions/183-k2filter) or another one [here](http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/extensions/ja-k2-search)

Comment: We used the second option mentioned here on this website: http://ashfm.ca after going through five or six different search components. This was the best of the batch.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "normal search" you must mean the build in Joomla module.
K2 has a search module that supports search in extra fields.

New module -> **K2 Tools** -> Select module functionality **Search Box**

*There is an issue with the K2 v2.7.1 search but the K2 v2.7.0 works as you need it.

As for your second question Yootheme Zoo is the next best thing but it's paid download while K2 is free.

Answer (score 0):

I realy belive you need know Zoo from Yootheme and Zoolanders module filter. 
This complete solution for your needs.

http://yootheme.com/zoo/

https://www.zoolanders.com/extensions/zoofilter